# Salesforce "Peer not authenticated" through wso2 SOAP

Tags: authentication

I am working off the following wso2 documentation [wso2 salesforce connector](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Salesforce+Connector+and+Streaming+Inbound+Endpoint) and specifically the [configuration](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESBCONNECTORS/Configuring+Salesforce+Connector+Operations) shown here. I have successfully imported my certificate into my client-truststore.jks, received my emailed token and then set up the following.

```xml
<salesforce.init>
    <username>itdeveloper@mycompany.com</username>
    <password>mypasswordandmytoken</password>
    <loginUrl>https://test.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/39.0</loginUrl>
    <blocking>true</blocking>
</salesforce.init>
```

The above stubbed information is correct in the actual version (if it's incorrect I get an INVALID_LOGIN error which I don't). Performing any simple SOAP query gives me a "peer not authenticated" error.

**Example query that gives the error:**

```xml
<salesforce.queryAll>
    <batchSize>200</batchSize>
    <queryString>SELECT Id FROM Account</queryString>
</salesforce.queryAll>
```

**Full error:**

> INFO {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender} -  Unable to sendViaPost to url [https://mycompany.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/39.0/00D0j000000Ctw4] {org.apache.axis2.transport.http.HTTPSender}
>       javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: peer not authenticated

Does anyone know how to resolve this peer authentication error? While similar in title this [other question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/58233/peer-not-authenticated-error) doesn't resolve what I am experiencing.

Comment: I don't know for sure, but this has a very strong smell of being a TLS 1.0 issue. See [Salesforce disabling TLS 1.0](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000221207&type=1). See the instructions for Java support in that article.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I'll see if that leads to some resolution. If it does you can type it into an answer and I'll accept.

Comment: So I was wrong in thinking that it wasn't a certificate error. It was but it wasn't through the server I thought. I'll explain in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Peer not authenticated" error turned out to be a certificate problem after all.

The wso2 esb was on a server named *myserver.mycompany.com* and I had installed that certificate. But, looking through the logs I found out that I was connecting to Salesforce through *mycompany--dev.my.salesforce.com*. Installing that certificate solved the problem.